# Threads and sockets, threads and objects more generally

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winsock

Thanks for your time.

*What am I trying to accomplish?*
I'm trying to utilise threads to speed up my program. After some profiling I found that a large portion of my program time (a graphics application) is utilised checking on the status of my socket. Obviously not ideal when trying to trim the fat and get down to <16ms per cycle. I'm currently using the select function to check for new data and read if data is available.

*What's the problem?*
I can't get my head around threads & objects, I had a play with some textbook examples running and joining local functions with threads which worked fine. Trying to move this into my own code has proved beyond me.

*What have I tried?*
I've tried looking to smart pointers to allocate my UDPSocket objects on the heap, with the hope that heap memory is accessible by all threads. I've tried good old new & delete for the same reason. I've tried wrapping my UDPSockets inside another object and getting the whole lot to launch on another thread.

*In summary* It's absolutely certain that I have a big hole in my understanding of threads, I would be grateful for a solution to this specific problem but also links to any good articles, tutorials, video's etc that might help to further my understanding. Perhaps I simply need to re-examine my whole UDPSocket class? Your advice is most welcome.

I'll post my example below, please note I've stripped out all error checking etc for readability.

```
#pragma once
#define WIN32_MEAN_AND_LEAN
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")


class UDPServer
{

public:
    UDPServer(unsigned short port_in)
        :
        port(port_in)
    {
        // Startup Winsock
        WSADATA data;
        WORD version = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
        int wsOk = WSAStartup(version, &data);

        //Bind socket to port, Any Address
        s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
        //Hint structure
        sockaddr_in serverHint;
        serverHint.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = ADDR_ANY;
        serverHint.sin_family = AF_INET;
        serverHint.sin_port = htons(port);

        bind(s, (sockaddr*)&serverHint, sizeof(serverHint));
    
    }
    ~UDPServer()
    {
        closesocket(s);
        WSACleanup();
    }

    bool Recieve()
    {
        ZeroMemory(&client, clientLength);

        if (dataAvailable(s))
        {
            ZeroMemory(messageBuffer, bufferSize);
            int bytesIn = recvfrom(s, messageBuffer, bufferSize, 0, (sockaddr*)&client, &clientLength);
            char clientIP[bufferSize];
            ZeroMemory(clientIP, bufferSize);
            inet_ntop(AF_INET, &client.sin_addr, clientIP, 256);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    std::string GetNetworkMessage()
    {
        std::string message = messageBuffer;
        return message;
    }

private:
    bool dataAvailable(int sock, int interval = 6000)
    {
        fd_set fds;
        FD_ZERO(&fds);
        FD_SET(sock, &fds);
        timeval tv;
        tv.tv_sec = 0;
        tv.tv_usec = interval;

        return (select(sock + 1, &fds, 0, 0, &tv) == 1);
    }
private:
    SOCKET s;
    sockaddr_in client;
    int clientLength = sizeof(client);
    static constexpr int bufferSize = 512;
    unsigned short port;
    char messageBuffer[bufferSize] = {};

};

int main()
{
    //Create server object on the heap.
    std::unique_ptr<UDPServer> udp = std::make_unique<UDPServer>(6000);

    //Get some new threads mate.
    std::thread theThread;
    std::string oldString = "";
    while (true)
    {
        //Problems...
        theThread = std::thread{udp->Recieve()};
        if (udp->GetNetworkMessage() != oldString)
        {
            //print out any changed data we find.
            oldString = udp->GetNetworkMessage();
            std::cout << oldString << std::endl;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: The key to multi threading is ensuring the data you have remains in a valid state. Such as not editing a variable in one thread whilst another reads it. If you want to speed up your program, specific profiling will help e.g. if most of the processing occurs in `ZeroMemory`, you could try avoiding unnecessary allocations and de-allocations. If you just want to run a function asynchronously without much overhead then `std::async` is a good choice.

Comment: Not sure your `UDPServer` can handle threaded accesses to `Recieve`.

Comment: `theThread = std::thread{udp->Recieve()};` this creates a new thread object each time around the loop. Threads are relatively expensive to make, I would create a thread pool so that threads are created only once. Then the main thread (doing the select and read) will read data from the socket and hand over the data package to be processed by the thread(s) in the pool allowing it to immediately go back to listening for more packets on the socket.

Comment: @MartinYork, in regards to my UDPServer being able to handle threaded access to Receive, you are almost certainly correct haha. Could you point me to any good resources to learn about thread pools? There is a lot out there from a quick google, but it seems like a massive can of worms and I wold like a solid source.

Answer (score 0):

One of the items you weren't clear on is memory accessibility in threads. In Windows, and likely most other operating systems, any memory accessible in the main thread is also accessible by every other thread in the same process.

There are two issues with regards to threads and that memory. The first is how can more than one thread know where a given variable or class is in memory. This is generally solved by passing a pointer to the new thread when it is created. Most thread creation mechanisms provide a parameter for this. So this is the easier issue to solve.

The harder issue to solve is making sure that one thread doesn't change a variable or class while another thread is using it. Generally this is solved by using a mutual exclusion synchronization object, generally referred to as a mutex or a lock. I suggest learning about the concept of a mutex. But bottom line it only allows one thread at a time to access whatever is locked by that mutex. So if one thread is busy changing or using that object the other thread will wait until the other thread has unlocked the object before continuing.

But when you get into multiple locks, there is something called a deadlock. A simple is demonstrated by: Thread A hold lock 1 and is waiting to get access to lock 2. Thread B meanwhile is holding lock 2 and waiting for access to lock 1. So both threads are stuck waiting on the other. The solution is that anytime you have to hold two locks always take them in the same order. So in this case if both threads always took lock 1 then lock 2 they can't deadlock.

The subject matter you want to learn about is threads and thread synchronization.